# Nodejs only specific logged users can get message

Tags: javascript, node.js

when users online and don't close our clients such as browser tab or android application, i can send message to each specific user by

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketId)
    .emit('new message', {
        username: data.fromUsername,
        money   : 'Hurrraaa'
    });
```

when users close clients as mobile application this event don't trigger but i can send any message to broadcast as:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('new message', "hooooorrrrraaaaa");
```

my users don't use client application any time, but i need to send message to some specific user and notify user until opening application and see message, users should be on'time in my application to get every message which i want to send from server like with Chat messengers which don't need users currently are using application such as WhatsApp,  how can i resolve this problem?

then problem is send message to some specific users when they are istalled application and logged ti sever, but not using now and application waiting to receive message such as broadcast or special message to himself

**this code is my simplified server:**

```
var socket      = require('socket.io'),
    express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    server      = require('http').createServer(app),
    io          = socket.listen(server),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    mysql       = require('mysql'),
    uuid        = require('node-uuid'),
    datetime    = require('node-datetime'),
    moment      = require('moment'),
    bcrypt      = require('bcrypt'),
    async       = require('async'),
    request     = require('request'),
    redis       = require("redis"),
    redisClient = redis.createClient(),
    forever     = require('forever'),
    log         = require('log4node');

var io_redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(io_redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));

require('sticky-socket-cluster/replace-console')();

var options = {
    workers     : require('os').cpus().length,
    first_port  : 8000,
    proxy_port  : 3000,
    session_hash: function (req, res) {
        return req.connection.remoteAddress;
    },

    no_sockets: false
};

require('sticky-socket-cluster')(options, start);

function start(port) {
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('new message', function (data) {
            socket.broadcast.emit('new message', "hooooorrrrraaaaa");
        });

        socket.on('login', function (data) {
            log.info(JSON.stringify(data))
            login(data.username, data.password, function (success, value) {
                if (success) {
                    redisClient.exists(data.username, function (err, doesExist) {
                        if (err) return;
                        if (!doesExist) {
                            redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id, function (err, res) {
                                redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            redisClient.del(data.username);
                            redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id, function (err, res) {
                                redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    socket.emit('login', {
                        result                : true,
                        id                    : value.id,
                        registeredMobileNumber: value.registeredMobileNumber
                    });
                } else {
                    socket.emit('login', {result: false});
                }
            });
        });

        socket.on('userConnected', function (username) {
            redisClient.exists(username, function (err, doesExist) {
                if (err) return;
                if (!doesExist) {
                    redisClient.set(username, socket.id, function (err, res) {
                        redisClient.set(username, socket.id);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    redisClient.del(username);
                    redisClient.set(username, socket.id, function (err, res) {
                        redisClient.set(username, socket.id);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        socket.on('disconnectUser', function (data) {
            redisClient.exists(data.username, function (err, doesExist) {
                if (err) return;
                if (doesExist) {
                    redisClient.del(data.username);
                }
            });
        });

        server.listen(port, function () {
            console.log('Express and socket.io listening on port ' + port);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `socket.on('disconnect', function() {});`

- When a User disconnects , save the users user_id.
- Subsequent message on the user_id would be saved in the server.
- When the client reconnects again get the time of the latest message and then push the message after that time (saved in the server) to the client.

Comment: this solution could not implement on'time feature for users, because when user is disconnect, then couldn't get message, but i want to user to be online and get message every time

Comment: You should use polling , when user closes the App , keep a background service running which will periodically check whether new messages have arrived or not.

Comment: you mean is polling instead of `websocket`? set clients transports to polling?

Comment: That may be one way , but I was talking about periodically connecting and checking for new messages in the client. like about every 5 sec , connect to the server.

Comment: Thats right, It seems i don't have any other solution, and i must be reconnect to server every 5 second